# why am i getting '+' sign instead of ',' when using split in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, split

i have a .txt file that have some phrases (pick up lines) with every phrase in a new line.
*here's a sample*

```
Does this rag smell like chloroform to you?
I have amnesia - do I come here often?
Your lips look lonely. Let me introduce them to mine
Your shirt has to go, but you can stay
```

and i want to create an array, so that every line is an element in this array.
*so i did this in node*

```
const fs = require('fs')

let a = fs.readFileSync('database.txt', 'utf-8')
b = a.split('/n')

console.log(b)
```

but i get just my test back with a plus sign between lines.

Comment: Do you mean `\n` not `/n`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to split line by backslash '\n'

```
    b = a.split('\n')
```